# antd data expandable if i have more than selection for a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

if i selected more than one selection antd form multiple selection item , i want the selected data appear in  the table field as, firstelement +remaing elements number, if i clicked the it needs to expand to right and display remaining data: if selected 3elements: one +2  if i click +2 => one two three . please react js and ant design community.

i have tried in here with render for the specific column const colums= []. it only displaying the number when iclicked right side and showing elements when i clicked left side drawer. i am expecting the data to be displayed when i clicked the number, i want the number to appear , when i loaded the page itself.

if selected 3elements: one +2  if i click +2 => one two three . please react js and ant design community.